# MA terms in arima

Tags: r, modeling, arima

With the arima function I found some nice results, however now I have trouble interpreting them for use outside R.
I am currently struggling with the MA terms, here is a short example:

```
ser=c(1, 14, 3, 9)        #Example series
mod=arima(ser,c(0,0,1))   #From {stats} library
mod

#Series: ser
#ARIMA(0,0,1) with non-zero mean
#
#Coefficients:
#          ma1  intercept
#      -0.9999     7.1000
#s.e.   0.5982     0.8762
#
#sigma^2 estimated as 7.676:  log likelihood = -10.56
#AIC = 27.11   AICc = Inf   BIC = 25.27

mod$resid

#Time Series:
#Start = 1
#End = 4
#Frequency = 1
#[1] -4.3136670  3.1436951 -1.3280435  0.6708065

predict(mod,n.ahead=5)

#$pred
#Time Series:
#Start = 5
#End = 9
#Frequency = 1
#[1] 6.500081 7.100027 7.100027 7.100027 7.100027
#
#$se
#Time Series:
#Start = 5
#End = 9
#Frequency = 1
#[1] 3.034798 3.917908 3.917908 3.917908 3.917908
?arima
```

When looking at the specification this formula is presented:
`X[t] = a[1]X[t-1] + … + a[p]X[t-p] + e[t] + b[1]e[t-1] + … + b[q]e[t-q]`

Given my choice of AR and MA terms, and considering that I have included a constant this should reduce to:
`X[t] =  e[t] + b[1]e[t-1] + constant`

However this does not hold up when i compare the results from R with manual calculations:
`6.500081 != 6.429261 == -0.9999 * 0.6708065 + 7.1000`

Furthermore I can also not succeed in reproducing the insample errors, assuming i know the first one this should be possible:
`-4.3136670 * -0.9999 +7.1000 !=  14 - 3.1436951`
`3.1436951 * -0.9999 +7.1000 !=   3 + 1.3280435`
`-1.3280435 * -0.9999 +7.1000 !=  9 - 0.6708065`

I hope someone can shed some light on this matter so I will actually be able to use the nice results that I have obtained.

Comment: Crossposted from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617369/ma-terms-in-arima](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617369/ma-terms-in-arima)

Comment: I just tried this with a much longer series, e <- rnorm(1001); y <- e[-1] + 0.5*e[-1001]  and the numbers came out fine.  I also replicated your problem.  I have no idea what happened with your series; I can only suspect its shortness caused some problem!  Very interesting.

Comment: AN MA 1 coefficient of -.999999 indicates that you have a very questionable model. Try using the Box-Jenkins method of identification in order to form your model. If you post your data I will try and help you ( after the new year ! )

Comment: Thank you very much for the replies, I have tried whether it is caused by the length by substituting the first line with ser=rep(c(1, 14, 3, 9),100) but this still did not provide the desired result. Therefore I conclude it must be the awkwardness of the test model that is causing the problem as suggested by IrishStat . I will leave it open for a few days, but if there are no new insights I will accept this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to debug predict.  Predict function is calling KalmanForecast(...). The above function calling a foreign function (*.Call("KalmanFore"...)* ). So I stopped here. I checked the help and found this line "Finite-history prediction is used, via KalmanForecast.This is only statistically efficient if the MA part of the fit is invertible, so predict.Arima will give a warning for non-invertible MA models." (see the R help).
 The above case is near non-invertible case(theta= -0.9999) and this would be the reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: Yeah I suppose this must be the cause of the problem. It would be nice though if these strange results were accompanied by a warning.
Either way, I am now confident enough to interpret the result I obtained by modeling an actual dataset (which is definately invertable)